# Work with global variables in React which are supplied at runtime and therefore unknown at build time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I am working on a App for Overwolf http://developers.overwolf.com/documentation/sdk/overwolf/

The Apps for this platform are html/js applications executed in the Overwolf Browser. The browser exposes the Overwolf API through a global variable `overwolf` so for example a call to the API would look like this:

```
overwolf.windows.getCurrentWindow(function callback(res) {
    var id = res.window.id;
    overwolf.windows.close(id, function callback() {
        logger.warning("Closing App!");
    });
});
```

(Notice that no script is imported, the API is exposed by the browser)
I am currently trying to migrate my plain JS application to React and am facing some issues with the way their API is exposed. As I am not importing any kind of script React doesn't know about that global variable and will fail to compile with the error:

`Line 6:  'overwolf' is not defined  no-undef`

I tried to workaround this problem like this :

`const overwolf = typeof overwolf === 'undefined' ? null : overwolf;`

In this instance overwolf would be overwritten to null always.
If I try like this

```
const overwolfGlobal = typeof overwolf === 'undefined' ? null : overwolf;
```

the react compiler will complain about the `typeof overwolf` again.

So my generic question is:
How can I work with global variables which are supplied at runtime and are therefore unknown to React (and Webpack)

Comment: is there a `window` object like in other browsers?

Comment: If you’re using webpack, try defining an external for overwolf in your webpack config

Comment: I'll try the external approach thanks

Comment: @PatrickHund external approach worked, Thanks! if you wan't to make an answer out of it, I would accept it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the `externals` configuration option on your webpack config object.
The following tells *Webpack* that `overwolf` library should be available as a global variable:

```
externals: {
  overwolf: {
    root: 'overwolf'
  }
}
```

Read more about [Webpack externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/#externals):

> **Prevent bundling** of certain `import`ed packages and instead retrieve these *external dependencies* at runtime.

Comment: Thanks this fixed it for production build, however on dev-server it will still throw an error, do you know of a way to mock the external on dev-server?

Comment: I have no experience working with the **overwolf browser**, but should work using the same *webpack config* in that browser (assumption: the environment provides the `overwolf` global variable). If not, you should consider add a script (if exist) providing such object. If the issue persist, please create another question and let me know the link so I can check and provide a more helpful answer. Cheers!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49323533/mocking-external-imports-in-development-environment-using-webpack-and-react/49323683#49323683 this is the question to the problem

Comment: I just add a possible solution for your `webpack-dev-server` scenario.. I think my [webpack-demo](https://github.com/carloluis/webpack-demo) can help you with some configurations with webpack an a possible migration to the latest version if you are not using it already.